# Convert Protocol Binary to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers

I am trying to convert protocol binary to JSON and wondering if there is a python package to help. Essentially, I want to do the same thing as `protoc --decode_raw` from command line, but in python.

Here are the steps I take in command line

```
aws kinesis get-records --limit 1 --shard-iterator AAAAAAAAAAGnyjeVQ5xQiKM4h2wLfvRxs5NoQzo5lijjqXnzcd3S2ZbPeN3PY3TSEfX2/yanQ0tMoAK3/ly2BaNqmX1z1q4MvguqzbYlxUyW7vLhlA/I5v0B+OR5zSsrws9j+mcL/YjHrxKVFVI3FXCfTASYagiRm0AvmfgR3tMSA8fdbG7U7nVfkBvliSmCCtf/+Ky/JuZGhhuLS7KAe0pk+7Qf2HhB | jq '.Records[0].Data' -r | base64 --decode
```

giving the output:

> $ ni�Y�*�@
>   � �(208BimpHPY
>   �`�]%@`i
>   �`�]%@q�j�4@y��Q@���Q
>   178.195.156.0�CH�07������^���&5-ef480d0d-ceca-425f-8a9b-3a8b508443e8������������+�>play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fingersoft.hillclimb��Φ���������2�����ݐ�������$����?���������cpm��Q���?��Q���?����2fHX$2?����USD�USD��?��4.10.0�com.fingersoft.hillclimb�������1203��$566b7011-1902-46c2-a0ed-0dcdf3475537��(����u����---�

If I add `| protoc --decode_raw` to the end then it decodes fine. I want to be able to decode this and convert it to JSON using Python. Note that I tried to use google.protobuf.json_format but because the input is protocol binary and not a protocol message it won't work.

Comment: use utf-8 and decode the data then you can convert the data into dictionary which is equivalent to JSON

Comment: When I try that I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 1: invalid start byte`. Any thoughts?

Comment: check out this link https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html